# blockUI javascript error when using local script files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blockui

I'm trying to use blockUI offline in my asp.net application. I have created two js files, one for [jquery](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js) and one for [blockUI script](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js)

I then referenced these two files in my .aspx page as follows:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

and here's an example of how I use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         Page = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         Page.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
         Page.add_endRequest(endRequest);

         function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
             $('div#blockme').block({
                 message: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...',
                 overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
             });
         }
         function endRequest(sender, args) {
             $('div#blockme').unblock();
         }

    </script>
```

However, when i run it, i get a javascript error "object does not support method 'block'" which I've understood from other posts that it is because jquery or blockUI were not loaded correctly.

But when I use the online scripts, the application works fine:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

I need to be using it offline so I won't be able to use the online scripts.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in referencing the local files?

Answer (score 1):

If ASPX or Master page is inside a folder *(other than root level)*, you can use one of the following approach -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js") %>" 
     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js") %>" 
     type="text/javascript"></script>
```